# How to make a BaoFeng start/end transmission with sound

Tags: baofeng

I recently went on a ride with my local police department. I heard two beeps at the start of their transmission, and a static-ey sound at the end.

I use the BaoFeng UV-5R+, and was wondering if there was a way to turn on those sounds when I transmit?

Comment: The static-ey sound is most likely by virtue of the squelch hang time or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Some of my local public service agencies (fire/police) use sound at the beginning of the transmission (BOT) as a PTT ID (a.k.a. ANI-ID or "signal ID") giving dispatch the ability to see which unit number is transmitting.  The PTT id is programmed into the radio by our local Kenwood radio re-seller upon request, matching the individual's or vehicle's assigned unit number.  A brief search for ANI-ID and the UV5R yielded references to menu 15.

The BOT tone is quite useful for the following: Someone accidentally keys the mic and you know who it is. A weak signal is heard, dispatch is unable to copy the unit number, but they can see it on the radio console. You forgot who the last person to transmit was but you can see their unit number on the radio display and call back to them.

A particular fire agency in the area uses an end of transmission (EOT) tone which in their case appears to be a glorified roger beep. Searches lead me to menu 39, "ROGER" on the UV5R menu.

The EOT tone is controversial as some people believe "roger beeps" are annoying while others argue that it helps prevent units from transmitting before the other is finished as they get used to waiting for the EOT tone.

Answer (score 2):

The double beep that you heard is probably from a trunking radio system or a repeater. As such, you cannot emulate this sound with your radio.

Answer (score 1):

I'll confirm what Steve said above, the ROGER menu item (adding tones at the end of the transmission) is probably the closest you'll get in a Baofeng.

But I would also point out that if you're operating on a repeater, you're likely to draw some criticism because most repeaters already signal the end of their (re)transmission with a courtesy tone.  So the ROGER beep generated by the radio ends up being redundant.

Answer (score -2):

Set the STE in menu to off that will add some repeater sound in the end of transmission